# rosserial - cannot import [custom messages] package

Tags: arduino, rosserial, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am having trouble using a custom ROS message type on my Arduino. I believe I have the latest version of ros-fuerte-rosserial

I have written & compiled a custom package called arduino_msgs, which worked since rosmsg show finds it.
I have ran rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py to "bind" it to my arduino libraries, and I have received a good ouput.

My arduino node has two subscribers & one publisher. The publisher uses an arduino_msgs message type, and the subscribers are std_msgs. When I run rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0, I get the following output (lunarex is the name of my computer..)

```
    lunarex@LunarEx:~/McGill_LunarEx_2013/Arduino$ rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyACM0[INFO] [WallTime: 1366251538.465538] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1366251538.474754] Connected on /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.605275] Cannot import package : arduino_msgs
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.607357] sys.path was ['/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_msgs/src', '/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_python/src', '/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes', '/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/home/lunarex/McGill_LunarEx_2013/Arduino', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.609387] Failed to parse publisher: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'msg'
[INFO] [WallTime: 1366251540.619060] Setup Subscriber on ang_speed [std_msgs/Float32]
[INFO] [WallTime: 1366251540.630073] Setup Subscriber on lin_speed [std_msgs/Float32]
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.633170] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.640945] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.656522] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.674111] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.685796] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1366251540.702021] Tried to publish before configured, topic id 125
```

..ad infinitum

so the bottom line is that my custom package (arduino_msgs) cannot be imported by rosserial, and therefore I cannot publish to a topic with that message type. Everything else works fine, so I can work around it using std_msgs, but if someone could point me to a solution that would be great.

Thanks!
Ernest

**---EDIT---**

I have acted upon fergs's three suggestions.

1. rosmake arduino_msgs produces this correct output

   [ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
   [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['arduino_msgs']
   [ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/lunarex/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output20130427-200123
   [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['arduino_msgs'] to:
   ['arduino_msgs']
   [rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
   [rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs
   [rosmake-0] Starting >>> arduino_msgs [ make ]
   [rosmake-0] Finished <<< arduino_msgs [PASS] [ 5.27 seconds ]
   [ rosmake ] Results:
   [ rosmake ] Built 2 packages with 0 failures.
   [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
   [ rosmake ] /home/lunarex/.ros/rosmake
2. My CMakeFile.txt includes gen_msgs:

   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
   include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

   ## Set the build type.  Options are:

   ## Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage

   ## Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization

   ## Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization

   ## RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization

   ## MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries

   #set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

   rosbuild_init()

   #set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
   set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
   #set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
   set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

   #uncomment if you have defined messages
   rosbuild_genmsg()
   #uncomment if you have defined services
   #rosbuild_gensrv()

   #common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
   #rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
   #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
   #rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
   #rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
   #rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
   #target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
3. My ROS_PACKAGE_PATH includes the directory where arduino_msgs is declared. That directory is /home/lunarex/McGill_LunarEx_2013/ROS_workspace, and my ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is:

   /home/lunarex/nicksebtemp:/home/lunarex/nicksebtemp:/home/lunarex/McGill_LunarEx_2013/ROS_workspace:/opt/ros/fuerte/share:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks

I noticed that that directory is not in sys.path though, so I appended /home/lunarex/McGill_LunarEx_2013/ROS_workspace to it, but I still get the same error when I run serial_node.py..

Any further hints? Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60991/rosserial---cannot-import-%5Bcustom-messages%5D-package/) by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on ROS Answers with karma: 341 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmsg show uses the raw .msg file -- not the compiled python version of the message which rosserial is trying to load. Either arduino_msgs is not on your ROS package path, or you likely have not setup your CMakeLists.txt file to generate messages -- or you have not compiled your custom arduino_msgs package.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) on 2013-04-27**:
Hi,

Thank you for your response (& for rosserial!). I have performed your three suggestions to no avail. I have included more information as an edit to my question.